# Autocomplete using Javascript/Json just returns error box

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I am using a user control which I think might be leading to the problem as the example I followed is referencing an actual aspx default page, but could someone possibly help me out here. I am trying to setup an autocomplete textbox and all I seem to be getting the error popup. Can't figure out where my issue is. I have pasted the entire code with the exception of the `Page_Load` procedures.

---

### HTML

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Search Textbox.ascx.cs" Inherits="StagingApplication.Search.Search_Textbox" %>
<link href="../css/customPages.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtAutoComplete").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Search/Page%20Search%20Textbox.aspx/GetCategory",
                data: "{'CountryName':'" + $("#txtAutoComplete").val() + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="searchText" runat="server" class="textboxLargeInline" AutoCompleteType="Search"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" class="standardButton" OnClick="searchButton_Click"/>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="txtAutoComplete" />
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### CODE BEHIND

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[] GetCategory(string term)
{
    List<string> retCategory = new List<string>();
    string ConnectionString = Connect.Connect("Location");
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        string query = string.Format("SELECT TOP 1000 [CountryName] FROM [Location].[dbo].[Country] WHERE [CountryName] LIKE '%{0}%'", term);
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                retCategory.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    return retCategory.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Is "data: "{'CountryName':'" + $("#txtAutoComplete").val() + "'}"," a typo should it be "data: "{'term':'" + $("#txtAutoComplete").val() + "'}"," ?

Comment: @CmdrTallen Okay, changed that, but still receiving an error box.

Comment: change `error:function(result){...}` to `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}` and share details

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak This code makes nothing happen at all.

Comment: url: "Search/Page%20Search%20Textbox.aspx/GetCategory" try append slash before `Search` or try the url see what returns

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak Changed it to `/Search/Page...` and still receive the `Error` alert.\

Comment: What do you get when `http://myhost/Search/Page%20Search%20Textbox.aspx/GetCategory`

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak It returned the same page that I get normally only it looked like the css didn't appear.

Comment: then change `type: "POST"` to `type: "GET"` of ajax http request type